# Should we have to use Failover Group server name or Primary server name in SQL Server managed instance connection string

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, automatic-failover

We have configured a failover group for our SQL Server Managed Instance in Azure portal:

[image]

- **Primary Managed Instance** : myprod01.asbcdef.database.windows.net
- **Failover Group Name** : failover-myprod01.asbcdef.database.windows.net

My current connection string(uses Primary server name):

```
server=tcp:myprod01.asbcdef.database.windows.net,1433;
    Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Mydatabase;User Id=user;
    Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;
    TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Which server name should I have to use in connection string to make sure failover will happen in case of any issues, is it primary server or failover group name ?

Comment: I think you should connect to the  failover group name. So that when you test failover of your failover group using the Azure portal, the SQL service will not terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should connect to the failover group name. So that if Primary server down, it will auto migrate to the Secondary server. Our application will run uninterrupted.

Comment: If we use failover connection should we use same username and password in both primary and secondary. so that when failover happens it still connects right ?